# What do you do when you run out of Zombies?

Tags: zombies

When playing with the base game Zombies, is there an official rule for what to do when you run out of Zombies? I checked BGG and the official rulebook and found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the official rulebook doesn't cover this, but [their FAQ](http://www.twilightcreationsinc.com/en/zombies/faq/zombies.html) does:

> What if I run out of zombies or tokens?
>
> Use any kind of markers you can get a hold of. You can keep track of the zombies you have killed in other ways, such as glass beads, and return the zombies to the pool.

If you want more zombies, Twilight Creations sells a [Bag O' Zombies](http://store.fastcommerce.com/twilightcreationsinc/zombies-bagozombies-non-glow-ff8081811779a41e01177f9ee37a5943-p.html) for $10, which I believe contains 100 zombies.

Comment: I looked at that FAQ and somehow did not see that question there!  Good catch.

Comment: I usually take a zombie who's already in use but far from the action and unlikely to be involved in the rest of the game and re-use it. It's not quite the same when you're running away from glass beads!